# Way to override where jQuery-UI dialog places things in markup?

Tags: jquery-ui, dom, dialog

I am trying to get a simple jQuery UI dialog to work in an ASP.Net project. I have some buttons inside the dialog's `<div>`, but they weren't posting back. Upon closer inspection, for whatever reason when making the `<div>` a panel it moves it in the DOM so that it is the last tag before `</body>`. This would all be fine and dandy except for it also moves it outside of the `<form>` tag which is needed so that the buttons can do a postback.

What is the purpose of this behavior and how can I override it?

An example is here: http://jsbin.com/olumu4/

Looking at Firebug though I get this:
[alt text http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/9049/dialog.png](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/9049/dialog.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with jQuery/ASP.NET.

After you assign your modal like this

```
$(".modal-window").dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

do this

```
$(".modal-window").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

If you have more than one modal on a page, I've found it doesn't work as expected, so in that case when you call the open method on the modal, do this:

```
$('.modal-window').dialog('open').parent().appendTo($('form:first'));
```

If you want to have it auto-open. You can append it right after the model is assigned.

```
$(".modal-window").dialog({
    modal: true
    }).parent().appendTo($('form:first'));
```

Hope this helps,

Marko

Comment: I have it so that the modal will open upon page load(`autoOpen`). How would I fix that? Preferably how would I fix this from the `open` event of the dialog?

Comment: No problemo - happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before, an option is to setup an even on the $(form).submit that appends what is in the dialog to the form.